# HTML formatting in tag when part of a search

Tags: bug, search, tag-wiki, tag-search

Here's a view of the [`r` tag on SO](//stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r). The tag wiki is displayed with questions with that tag:

[image]

[Add another string to the search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+rcurl) and the tag wiki becomes borked:

[image]

It seems like words in the tag wiki that matches the tag have HTML tags associated with it. [The actual tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info) doesn't show these HTML tags.

[image]

[Another example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+python):

[image]

What's wrong? Can it be fixed?